# How to make Simplecoin's powerpool to support Litecoin Segwit?

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin, segregated-witness

I tweek the code transation.py  https://github.com/simplecrypto/cryptokit/blob/master/cryptokit/transaction.py#L150 add:

```
    if (self.default_witness_commitment is not None):
        data += b'\x00'
        data += b'\x01'
```

https://github.com/simplecrypto/cryptokit/blob/master/cryptokit/transaction.py#L173 add:

```
    if (self.default_witness_commitment is not None):
        combs = self.default_witness_commitment.decode("hex")
        data += b'\x6a'
        data += self.varlen_encode(len(combs)+4)
        data += b'\xaa\x21\xa9\xed'    
        data += combs
```

to match the BIP141  :https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#specification

However when I run it . I always getting 
CoinRPCException: Block decode failed

Any expert could help on this problem?

Reference:
base on the proposal: https://litecoincore.org/ltc-segwit-pool.pdf
and some reference :https://github.com/thrasher­/eloipool/commit/d488480c263c57a1e5151a6db3090d1413d3a054
https://github.com/zone117x/node­stratum­pool/pull/115
https://github.com/UNOMP/node­merged­pool/pull/4